# Reset SharePoint blog homepage

Tags: list, blog, view

I tried to change the filter applied to the blog posts displayed on the home page. I created a new view and applied it to the "posts" web part on the home page, and now it just displayed all the blog posts in a list.

How can I reset it back so that it will display the full content of each blog post like it does by default?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: Question answered here:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64378/how-to-restore-the-default-sharepoint-blog-homepage