# How to restore the default SharePoint Blog homepage

Tags: view

I have applied a different view to the blog homepage on my SharePoint blog site. Now it seems I cannot restore it to the original view where it displays all the blog posts and the content, and it now will only display a list of each blog post.

Is there a way to restore this? I basically just want a home page with all blog posts, I can do it by removing the site and making a whole new site, but I don't really want to do that.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010, edit the page add a new web part and select the posts list from Lists and Libraries section.  After the web part has been added, change the selected view to <summary view>.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe I spent hours on it when it was so simple.

Comment: If your *Categories* web part breaks, also add it the same way and switch to `<Summary view>` and `Summary Toolbar`.

Comment: This solution works for SharePoint Online Blogs as well, and If you enable Blog feature in site level instead of creating a Blog Sub Site.